# Need help converting my beautiful soup (Python) code to PHP

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently in the process of converting all of my beautiful soup code into PHP just to get used to PHP. However i've run into a bit of a problem, my php code will only work when the wiki page has 'External links' after the original run in the html (such as [True Detective Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Detective_(TV_series))). I just found out that this won't always happen because there may not always be an 'External links' section. I was wondering if there was anyway to convert my beautiful soup code into php code using the same technique my beautiful soup code uses?

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_date(url):
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    date = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "infobox"})

    for item in date:
        dates = item.find_all("th")
        for item2 in dates:
            if item2.text == "Original run":
                test2 = item2.find_next("td").text.encode("utf-8")
                mysub = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', test2)
                return my sub
```

and here is my php code currently

```
<?php
// Defining the basic cURL function
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
}
?>

<?php
// Defining the basic scraping function
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
}
?>

<?php
$scraped_page = curl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_series)");    // Downloading IMDB home page to variable $scraped_page
$scraped_data = scrape_between($scraped_page, "<table class=\"infobox vevent\" style=\"width:22em\">", "</table>");   // Scraping downloaded dara in $scraped_page for content between <title> and </title> tags
$original_run = mb_substr($scraped_data, strpos($scraped_data, "Original run")-2, strpos($scraped_data, "External links") - strpos($scraped_data, "Original run")-2);
echo $original_run;

?>
```

Comment: Could you add more on the motivation side of the question? Why are you switching from python+bs4 approach?

Comment: Use PHP SImple HTML DOM Parser then (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). But as @alecxe pointed could you explain why you are switching to PHP?

Comment: Because my original code for a website was done using Flask api for python and I want to try and move some of that code to PHP instead of keeping half my code in python

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply using [Wikipedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&titles=The%20Walking%20Dead%20(TV%20series))? Autogenerated wiki markup is generally incredibly terrible to deal with and may change at any time.

Additionally, instead of trying to regex-parse HTML or something in PHP, just use the [phpQuery](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/phpquery) library with composer, you can just search for the selector `table.infobox.vevent`.

---

Comment: Unfortunately the wikipedia api doesn't output Original run of the tv show(as far as I and ctrl-f can see)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=The%20Walking%20Dead%20%28TV%20series%29 ctrl+f first_aired, the "original run" is from a different included template